# Tiny Date/Time pickers appear in Chrome and Edge when data list available

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I'm not sure if this is only my machine! I tried to load a datalist in my HTML inputs, with Zoom 100% and the date-picker looks tiny!

Other scenarios that I tried

- Zoom the browser to 110% or above and the date-picker will work.
- Any Zoome value less than or equal 100% of the tiny popup will not appear.
- Remove the datalist everything works fine with all zoom values!
- Chrome and Edge have the same behavior.

**Note**:

- I tried incognito mode also.
- Chrome Version 115.0.5790.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

What is the problem?

```html
<input type="time" list="popularHours" />
<datalist id="popularHours">
  <option value="12:00"></option>
  <option value="13:00"></option>
  <option value="14:00"></option>
</datalist>
```

This is how it looks on my machine

[image]

Comment: Failed to reproduce this issue on my side. Both Edge and Chrome work fine. Have you tried clearing cache or something?

Comment: I tried incognito mode.

Comment: Then you can try clearing cache first. Also, how about the date picker in an independent HTML file instead of JSFiddle?